# Fast scroll in Robotium

Tags: android, scroll, robotium

I have created a test project for my Android project. In my app there is a listview that has a lot of data. I need to scroll this listview up and down using Robotium. I have used the `scrollUp()` and `scrollDown()` functions, but it is scrolling too slowly.

I am using Robotium 3.3. Is there any way to make a fast scroll?

Answer (score 4):

```
int screenWidth = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int screenHeight = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

         int fromX, toX, fromY, toY = 0,stepCount=1;

         // Scroll Down // Drag Up
         fromX = screenWidth/2;
         toX = screenWidth/2;
         fromY = (screenHeight/2) + (screenHeight/3);
         toY = (screenHeight/2) - (screenHeight/3);

solo.drag(fromX, toX, fromY, toY, stepCount);
```

here

[1] stepCount=1; // very fast scroll

[2] stepCount=10; // medium scroll

[3] stepCount=17; // slow scroll

So you adjust " stepCount " value according to your scroll required speed.

i hope this will help you for your better scroll list view.
Thanks.