# Robotium Drag does not work

Tags: android, testing, drag-and-drop, andengine, robotium

I have written a game using AndEngine that I want to test using Robotium. The problem is that robotium's drag function does not work. I have the robotum 4.0 jar added to the build path and exported, and my manifest file 
seems to be correct. The second test(joystick) fails as the movement never takes place. This is the test class:

```
package cs428.uiuc.robotswarms.test;

    import junit.framework.Assert;

    import org.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;


    import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;


    import cs428.uiuc.robotswarms.RobotSwarms;

    import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;


    public class testMotion extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<RobotSwarms> {

public testMotion() {
    super(RobotSwarms.class);
}

private Solo solo;

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}

private void waitForSpriteInitialisation(RobotSwarms ActivityData) {
    while (ActivityData.getPlayerSprite() == null) {

    }
}

public void testJoystickMovement() {
    RobotSwarms ActivityData = getActivity();
    final float fromX = 400.0f;
    float toX = 380.0f;
    final float fromY = 208.0f;
    float toY = 208.0f;
    AnimatedSprite playerSprite;
    waitForSpriteInitialisation(ActivityData);
    playerSprite = ActivityData.getPlayerSprite();
    float initialPlayerXPosition = playerSprite.getX();
    solo.sleep(2000);
    solo.drag(fromX, toX, fromY, toY, 5);
    solo.sleep(2000);

    playerSprite = ActivityData.getPlayerSprite();

    float playerMovedX = playerSprite.getX();
    Assert.assertTrue(playerMovedX != initialPlayerXPosition);

}


}
```

Target application manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cs428.uiuc.robotswarms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name="cs428.uiuc.robotswarms.RobotSwarms"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Test project manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cs428.uiuc.robotswarms.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="cs428.uiuc.robotswarms" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
```

I have tried using TouchUtils instead of Robotium but that does not seem to work either.
Edit: Bump

Comment: see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682196/fast-scroll-in-robotium/12658777#12658777, in this link you see that how to scroll or drag dynamic irrespective to screen size ... hope this will help you ...